# Cannot convert return expression of type 'P?' to return type 'UIViewController'

Tags: ios, swift

**I have a protocol which can applied only on UIViewController classes**.

**I have an array of objects which must respond to P protocol**

so when returning an object from the array I am sure that get a UIViewController class object.

Why the compiler return an error:

> Cannot convert return expression of type 'P' to return type
>   'UIViewController?'

```
protocol P where Self: UIViewController {
    func f ()
}

class A: UIViewController {

    let d: [P] = [P]()

    func m() -> UIViewController? {

        return self.d.first

    }

}
```

**Updated**

Swift 5.1 resolves this code without an error

Comment: remove .first from your return statement and it'll work just fine :)

Comment: `UIViewController` might not conform `P`, so it wont work, return `P?` instead

Comment: @Tj3n All objects in the arrray are objects of the UIViewController class due to a constraint which was applied on the P protocol. P protocol can be applied only on UIViewController class objects

Comment: You can also force convert to `UIViewController` like `return (self.d.first as? UIViewController)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiler, at this point, doesn't know that the `[P]` contains only `UIViewController` instances. It is probably a bug in Swift, since when you try to do the following, compiler complains

```
struct B: P {
  func test() {}
}
```

> 'P' requires that 'B' inherit from 'UIViewController'

A nice solution would be

```
class A: UIViewController {
  typealias PViewController = UIViewController & P
  let d: [PViewController] = [PViewController]()

  func m() -> UIViewController? {

      return self.d.first

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
protocol P {
    var viewController: UIViewController { get }
}

extension P where Self: UIViewController {
    var viewController: UIViewController {
        return self
    }
}

class A: UIViewController {
    let d: [P] = [P]()

    func m() -> UIViewController? {

        return self.d.first?.viewController

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This probably would work, because the compiler doesn't convert the type to the `Self` :

```
class A: UIViewController {

    let d: [P] = [P]()

    func m() -> UIViewController? {
        return self.d.first as? UIViewController
    }
}
```